# How to change my cron job to auto update the geolite2?

Tags: linux, cron, tar, curl

A Prestashop e-commerce website is using MaxMind's GeoLite2-City database for country blocking. Instead of `geoipupdate` it uses this `cron` command to keep that database up to date:

`/usr/bin/curl -L --silent 'http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-City.mmdb.gz' | /bin/zcat > '/home/u3p3/domains/xyz.tld/public_html/app/Resources/geoip/GeoLite2-City.mmdb'`

As of January 2020 the [geolite databases are no longer publicly available](https://blog.maxmind.com/2019/12/18/significant-changes-to-accessing-and-using-geolite2-databases/), and requires an account and license key. Within less then 21 days of not updating the geolite mmdb file, Prestashop is stopped with a 500 error:

> InvalidDatabaseException: Error opening database file.

How to make the cron job run again with the new license file from the new download location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Prestashop 1.7.x

This is the cron job that only extracts the `GeoLite2-City.mmdb` file from the zipped tar file to the location that the Prestashop built-in geoip module requires:

`/usr/bin/curl -L --silent 'https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=GeoLite2-City&license_key=YOUR_LICENSE_KEY&suffix=tar.gz' | /bin/tar -C '/home/u3p3/domains/xyz.tld/public_html/app/Resources/geoip' -xvz --keep-newer-files --strip-components=1 --wildcards '*GeoLite2-City.mmdb'`

#### --keep-newer-files

The "keep newer files" flag is here to reduce write i/o. Existing identical versions of the file are not overwritten. When there is no update in the upstream version, the tar output will become something like:

```
/bin/tar: Current `GeoLite2-City.mmdb' is newer or same age
```